# VoIP switch setup trouble

Tags: voip

I have a brocade icx 6450 with the following config.  The pc's are connected directly to the phones.

I have port 1/1/48 going into another switch which is has the dhcp server for the data network and port 1/2/1 going to another switch which has the dhcp server for the voip network.

Now the pc's get the dhcp requests fine but the phones do not work.  PLease tell me what I am doing wrong.

```
global-stp
!
!
!
vlan 1 name DEFAULT-VLAN by port
!
vlan 100 name DATA_VLAN by port
 tagged ethe 1/1/1 to 1/1/45 ethe 1/1/47
 untagged ethe 1/1/48
 router-interface ve 100
 spanning-tree 802-1w
!
vlan 150 name VOIP_VLAN by port
 tagged ethe 1/1/1 to 1/1/45 ethe 1/1/47 ethe 1/2/1
 untagged ethe 1/1/46
 router-interface ve 150
 spanning-tree 802-1w
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
boot sys fl sec
enable telnet password .....
enable super-user-password .....
no ip forward-protocol udp dns

!
!
interface ethernet 1/1/1
 dual-mode  100
 spanning-tree 802-1w admin-edge-port
 inline power
 voice-vlan 150
 trust dscp
!
interface ethernet 1/1/2
 dual-mode  100
 spanning-tree 802-1w admin-edge-port
 voice-vlan 150
 trust dscp
!
interface ethernet 1/1/3
 dual-mode  100
 spanning-tree 802-1w admin-edge-port
 inline power
 voice-vlan 150
 trust dscp
!
interface ethernet 1/1/4
 dual-mode  100
 spanning-tree 802-1w admin-edge-port
 inline power
 voice-vlan 150
 trust dscp
!
interface ethernet 1/1/5
 dual-mode  100
 spanning-tree 802-1w admin-edge-port
 inline power
 voice-vlan 150
 trust dscp
!
interface ethernet 1/1/6
 dual-mode  100
 spanning-tree 802-1w admin-edge-port
 inline power
 voice-vlan 150
 trust dscp
!
interface ethernet 1/1/7
 dual-mode  100
 spanning-tree 802-1w admin-edge-port
 inline power
 voice-vlan 150
 trust dscp
!
interface ethernet 1/1/8
 dual-mode  100
 spanning-tree 802-1w admin-edge-port
 inline power
 voice-vlan 150
 trust dscp
!
interface ethernet 1/1/9
 dual-mode  100
 spanning-tree 802-1w admin-edge-port
 inline power
 voice-vlan 150
 trust dscp
!
interface ethernet 1/1/10
 dual-mode  100
 spanning-tree 802-1w admin-edge-port
 inline power
 voice-vlan 150
 trust dscp
!
interface ethernet 1/1/11
 dual-mode  100
 spanning-tree 802-1w admin-edge-port
 voice-vlan 150
 trust dscp
!
interface ethernet 1/1/12
 dual-mode  100
 spanning-tree 802-1w admin-edge-port
 voice-vlan 150
 trust dscp
!
interface ethernet 1/1/13
 dual-mode  100
 spanning-tree 802-1w admin-edge-port
 voice-vlan 150
 trust dscp
!
interface ethernet 1/1/14
 dual-mode  100
 spanning-tree 802-1w admin-edge-port
 voice-vlan 150
 trust dscp
!
interface ethernet 1/1/15
 dual-mode  100
 spanning-tree 802-1w admin-edge-port
 voice-vlan 150
 trust dscp
!
interface ethernet 1/1/16
 dual-mode  100
 spanning-tree 802-1w admin-edge-port
 inline power
 voice-vlan 150
 trust dscp
!
interface ethernet 1/1/17
 dual-mode  100
 spanning-tree 802-1w admin-edge-port
 voice-vlan 150
 trust dscp
!
interface ethernet 1/1/18
 dual-mode  100
 spanning-tree 802-1w admin-edge-port
 inline power
 voice-vlan 150
 trust dscp
!
interface ethernet 1/1/19
 dual-mode  100
 spanning-tree 802-1w admin-edge-port
 voice-vlan 150
 trust dscp
!
interface ethernet 1/1/20
 dual-mode  100
 spanning-tree 802-1w admin-edge-port
 inline power
 voice-vlan 150
 trust dscp
!
interface ethernet 1/1/21
 dual-mode  100
 spanning-tree 802-1w admin-edge-port
 voice-vlan 150
 trust dscp
!
interface ethernet 1/1/22
 dual-mode  100
 spanning-tree 802-1w admin-edge-port
 inline power
 voice-vlan 150
 trust dscp
!
interface ethernet 1/1/23
 dual-mode  100
 spanning-tree 802-1w admin-edge-port
 voice-vlan 150
 trust dscp
!
interface ethernet 1/1/24
 dual-mode  100
 spanning-tree 802-1w admin-edge-port
 inline power
 voice-vlan 150
 trust dscp
!
interface ethernet 1/1/25
 dual-mode  100
 spanning-tree 802-1w admin-edge-port
 voice-vlan 150
 trust dscp
!
interface ethernet 1/1/26
 dual-mode  100
 spanning-tree 802-1w admin-edge-port
 inline power
 voice-vlan 150
 trust dscp
!
interface ethernet 1/1/27
 dual-mode  100
 spanning-tree 802-1w admin-edge-port
 voice-vlan 150
 trust dscp
!
interface ethernet 1/1/28
 dual-mode  100
 spanning-tree 802-1w admin-edge-port
 inline power
 voice-vlan 150
 trust dscp
!
interface ethernet 1/1/29
 dual-mode  100
 spanning-tree 802-1w admin-edge-port
 voice-vlan 150
 trust dscp
!
interface ethernet 1/1/30
 dual-mode  100
 spanning-tree 802-1w admin-edge-port
 inline power
 voice-vlan 150
 trust dscp
!
interface ethernet 1/1/31
 dual-mode  100
 spanning-tree 802-1w admin-edge-port
 voice-vlan 150
 trust dscp
!
interface ethernet 1/1/32
 dual-mode  100
 spanning-tree 802-1w admin-edge-port
 voice-vlan 150
 trust dscp
!
interface ethernet 1/1/33
 dual-mode  100
 spanning-tree 802-1w admin-edge-port
 voice-vlan 150
 trust dscp
!
interface ethernet 1/1/34
 dual-mode  100
 spanning-tree 802-1w admin-edge-port
 inline power
 voice-vlan 150
 trust dscp
!
interface ethernet 1/1/35
 dual-mode  100
 spanning-tree 802-1w admin-edge-port
 voice-vlan 150
 trust dscp
!
interface ethernet 1/1/36
 dual-mode  100
 spanning-tree 802-1w admin-edge-port
 voice-vlan 150
 trust dscp
!
interface ethernet 1/1/37
 dual-mode  100
 spanning-tree 802-1w admin-edge-port
 voice-vlan 150
 trust dscp
!
interface ethernet 1/1/38
 dual-mode  100
 spanning-tree 802-1w admin-edge-port
 voice-vlan 150
 trust dscp
!
interface ethernet 1/1/39
 dual-mode  100
 spanning-tree 802-1w admin-edge-port
 voice-vlan 150
 trust dscp
!
interface ethernet 1/1/40
 dual-mode  100
   spanning-tree 802-1w admin-edge-port
 inline power
 voice-vlan 150
 trust dscp
!
interface ethernet 1/1/41
 dual-mode  100
 spanning-tree 802-1w admin-edge-port
 voice-vlan 150
 trust dscp
!
interface ethernet 1/1/42
 dual-mode  100
 spanning-tree 802-1w admin-edge-port
 inline power
 voice-vlan 150
 trust dscp
!
interface ethernet 1/1/43
 dual-mode  100
 spanning-tree 802-1w admin-edge-port
 voice-vlan 150
 trust dscp
!
interface ethernet 1/1/44
 dual-mode  100
 spanning-tree 802-1w admin-edge-port
 voice-vlan 150
 trust dscp
!
interface ethernet 1/1/45
 dual-mode  100
 spanning-tree 802-1w admin-edge-port
 voice-vlan 150
 trust dscp
!
interface ethernet 1/1/46
 spanning-tree 802-1w admin-edge-port
 trust dscp
!
interface ethernet 1/1/47
 dual-mode  100
 spanning-tree 802-1w admin-edge-port
 voice-vlan 150
 trust dscp
!
interface ethernet 1/1/48
 spanning-tree 802-1w admin-edge-port
 trust dscp
!
interface ethernet 1/2/1
 speed-duplex 1000-full-master
 spanning-tree 802-1w admin-pt2pt-mac
 trust dscp
!
interface ve 100
 ip helper-address 1 192.168.16.205
!
interface ve 150
 ip helper-address 1 10.50.1.1
!
!
!
!
!
end
```

Any idea?

Comment: sounds like the phones don't know their vlan is 150.

Comment: How is the switch with the voice dhcp server configured?  Specifically, what vlans are tagged/untagged on the trunk port?

Comment: 150 is the proper vlan on the voice dhcp server. If I modify the config a bit, get rid of the data vlan and set all ports (except port 1/2/1) to untagged (access ports), then the phones work fine. but i need to have both data/voice working on the same switch.

Comment: It sounds like to are not correctly trunking to the switch with the voice dhcp server.  Are the tagged ports matched correctly? Can you show a config of that switch?

Comment: @NetworkNinja As Ron said, are you able to post the configs of that switch?

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

Add IP addresses (gateway) to the `ve` interfaces. That way it has a source address to route the DHCP requests from.

i.e.

```
interface ve 100
 ip address 192.168.16.x 255.255.255.x
 ip helper-address 1 192.168.16.205
!
interface ve 150
 ip address 10.50.1.x 255.255.255.x
 ip helper-address 1 10.50.1.1
!
```

or whatever your subnet is that you're using.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know Brocade's device specifically, but the config seems pretty straightfoward.

Are you using Trunking (802.1Q) to have multiple VLANs between your switches? You seem to have more than one VLAN on the swich (150 + default) but only the default VLAN on your uplink port.

If that's the case and the Brocade automagically puts phones on VLAN 150 (Voice VLAN), their DHCP request will never be able to reach the other switch unless you're using IP Helpers, in which case, you seem to be missing IP addresses on your vlan interfaces.

So, if you're switching to the DHCP Server, there are VLANs issues (802.1q missing) while if routing to the DHCP server, there is no IP addresses on any interfaces, meaning it has no way to send/receive IP packets (no IP interfaces, no IP communication)

Comment: Hi Remi...in brocade world tag means the same as trunk in cisco terminology.  So on the voice vlan, port 1/2/1 is the trunk port to the voip switch which is doing the routing for the vlan and is dynamically assigning ip's.  If I modify the config a bit, get rid of the data vlan and set all ports (except port 1/2/1) to untagged (access ports), then the phones work fine. but i need to have both data/voice working on the same switch.